# Can GetCurrentProcess() be used in a class library?

Tags: c#, dll, process

Just like the title, I want to know that if Process.GetCurrentProcess() can be used in a class library and what it will do.
Actually I wrote a method like this:

```cs
        public static void WritePID(Process p)
        {
            Log.Write(tmpPath, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString());
        }
```

Now I want to move this method into a class library.
Will it work properly or throw an exception? (It means returning the process which called it)
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the difference between the 'static' method and the non-static type of method?

Comment: What would make you doubt it would work?

Comment: You seem to have a weird mental model - Processes don't call library methods. The closest one might say is that *threads* call *into* library methods. Whilst it's inside the library method, that thread hasn't magically changed into a new thread, and it's still a part of the same process it always was.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The degree to which a library method is called by a thread or by a process is equivalent.  In both cases you can have in-process libraries (most common for .NET) where the library runs in the context (process and thread) of the caller, and out-of-process COM servers where the library runs in its own context (different process and thread from the caller).  If you want to say "it isn't the process which is the caller, but some other function running inside the process", you aren't wrong but the exact same pedantry applies to threads.